# How do I generate a list with specified size of random integers within a range in Java 8?

Tags: java, arraylist, random, java-8, java-stream

I want to generate a list of random numbers between a specified range and of a certain size.

I've tried using streams, and I think this is probably the best solution. I couldn't get it working myself, but I have not learned enough about streams yet.

The following code works for my problem, but I'd like to be able to use something from the Java api if possible. If I were to use stream's `map` method, I would need to use a consumer with `n -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1)`, but I could not appropriately collect at the end of my stream.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRandList(100, 0, 10));
    }

    /**
     * Get n random integers within the range of min and max
     */
    static List<Integer> getRandList(int size, int min, int max) {
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            integers.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1));
        }
        return integers;
    }
}
```

The referenced duplicate does not address my question directly, I wanted a `List<Integer>` and Oleksandr's solution provides a `IntStream`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this,

```
List<Integer> integers = IntStream.range(0, size)
    .mapToObj(i -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the class "Random" for get random numbers.

Exemple :

```java
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt(bound);
```

After, do this with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first thought -

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);

List<Integer> list = nums.stream().map(n->ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,11)).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: This works kinda, but I wanted to declare the list in 1 line.

Comment: @William looks like Ravindra has more compact solution.